# Terraform Reserved VM Instances on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a windows VM in Azure using Terraform. However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to create the VM as a reserved instance for a 1 or 3 year plan.

Does anyone know if this is even doable with Terraform?

Answer (score 3):

Azure Reserved instances are applied through billing.  There isn't a technical mechanism for selecting a reserved instance.  It is easily confused for how AWS applies reserved instances.

On the surface it is fairly simply, you pay for a reservation and it gets applied.

> After you buy an Azure Reserved Virtual Machine Instance, the
> reservation discount is automatically applied to virtual machines that
> match the attributes and quantity of the reservation. A reservation
> covers the compute costs of your virtual machines.

But it can get fairly nuanced as you [read](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/reserved-vm-instances/) through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/understand-vm-reservation-charges?toc=/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/toc.json)

Comment: My final sentence seems snarky, but I didn't intend snark.  Just linking to the docs, and didn't want to try and rewrite what was written.  And with all things cloud it changes from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of azure and terraform but as far as i can see reservation are linked to subscription or to a resource group, so maybe you could configure it after resource creation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).